# Why i cannot acces to my files? Laravel Nginx

Tags: php, laravel, database, nginx

I have a problem with my project because I can't access my files in my server Nginx.
when I use asset to include my files inside tag's `<Iframe>` laravel generate me an error route.

this.

[image]

I don't know why laravel add a new slash after public  ( public//)

but I then try to include `iframes` static but the result is the same, the URL is correct but laravel return me an error 404.

[image]

the rest of my code and my site web is working ok, but i cannot include the files on my server.

I'm working with Nginx in ubuntu and laravel 8

Comment: show us the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I put the URL in the server's settings to can access the files.

nginx has a configuration and in this configuration, I put the URL public references to the files